# UriTemplate Wildcard to match Uri fragments with spaces in WCF WebGet method

Tags: wcf, iis-7, .net-4.0, uritemplate

I'm using a UriTemplate wildcard to match the whole URI string after the path to a WCF svc:

```
    [WebGet(
        UriTemplate = "feed/{*path}" 
        )]
```

However this only matches up until the first space (or '+' or '%20'), is it possible to get it to match spaces?

This works:
`/feed.svc/Folder`

These don't work (only returns up to the first space)

`/feed.svc/Folder Name`

`/feed.svc/Folder+Name`

`/feed.svc/Folder%20Name`

Cheers

Comment: Also it seems to ignore anything after an underscore, which unfortunately was my backup plan to replace with a space after the match! So /feed.svc/Folder_Name still only matches Folder

Comment: OMG arbitrary Reputation restrictions are POINTLESS! Here's the answer:

OK the culprit was the IIS rewrite rules I had in place:

    ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-\.\/\(\)]+)

This was not matching spaces so I just had to add the space character to the regex, ala:

    ^([ 0-9a-zA-Z\-\.\/\(\)]+)

Tada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK the culprit was the IIS rewrite rules I had in place:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z\-\.\/()]+)
```

This was not matching spaces so I just had to add the space character to the regex, ala:

```
^([ 0-9a-zA-Z\-\.\/()]+)
```

Tada!